# How to use GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How to utilise the group by in ***sequelize*** for mysql **GROUP BY YEAR(created at)**

I am trying by doing this but it shos an error

```
const result = await arbcase.findAll({
    attributes: [[arbcase.sequelize.literal(`COUNT(*)`), "count"]],
    group: ["YEAR(created_at)"],
  });
```

**error**
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'YEAR(created_at)' in 'group statement'",

'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `arbcase` AS `arbcase` GROUP BY `YEAR(created_at)`;'

Comment: Did you try `Sequelize.fn`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await arbcase.findAll({
attributes: [
  "created_at",
  [arbcase.sequelize.literal(`COUNT(*)`), "count"],
],
group: [
  arbcase.sequelize.fn("YEAR", arbcase.sequelize.col("created_at")),
  arbcase.sequelize.fn("MONTH", arbcase.sequelize.col("created_at")),
],
// SELECT created_at ,count(*) FROM `arbcase` GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at) ASC
```

});

This code is working for me

**your__mode__name**.sequelize.col("created_at"))

This function is used for every function in MySQL in Sequelize